# Forward my domain and hide the original

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, godaddy, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have registered a domain with godaddy. This points to a sub domain on app spot (google app engine).

When i visit my domain I see the blah.appspot.com rather than mydomain.com

Can I hide the app spot url somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you purchase your Domain through Google Apps?

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your problems isn't domain masking.  If you have GoDaddy, you can set this up without hurting your site's SEO with domain masking.

Basically, you need to do the following:

- Add your domain to App Engine's Administration section.
- Add your AppEngine project to your Google Apps panel.

If you purchased your domain through Google and GoDaddy, your A records should look as follows:

```
   216.239.32.21      @
   216.239.34.21      @
   216.239.36.21      @
   216.239.38.21      @
```

Your CNAME should have:

```
   www              ghs.google.com
```

In Google Apps, you can then configure the subdomain www to point to the App Engine project.

This is the recommended way of configuring your application for your domain.  Here is the link again:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html

Note that if you don't have Google Apps, you just have to prove to Google that you own the domain.

Comment: Hi @jmort253, I've registered a domain via Google Apps with GoDaddy, I can see all those IPs you listed plus a GoDaddy one on top "50.63.202.31". I'd like to permanently forward from this domain to another domain , I've set that up on GoDaddy's page but it's not working. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I've removed the CNAME for www to ghs.google.com, I'm now waiting to see if forwarding starts working. I don't understand why they suggest IPs like "64.202.189.170", I think what I already have should work the same

Comment: @ZiglioNZ - It's probably best if you post a new question and include all of the details of what you're trying to do and what you tried, outlining your exact DNS configuration. It sounds like your problem is different than the one outlined here. Feel free to drop a link to your new post here. Good luck! :)

Comment: thank you, I will. It's half working now (the naked domain gets redirected but not www)